# Return the mostly occured word in list

Tags: python

I have a list [wolf, wolf, cat]. I have a code for counting which is the most frequent word, but I do not know how to write that not the number should appear but the most frequent word? /without using any libraries/

> print((max(str(list.count))))

What I get -> 2

What I want -> wolf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> most frequent word **without using any libraries**

```
words = ['wolf', 'cat', 'dog', 'wolf']
d = {}

for w in words:
    d[w] = d[w] + 1 if d.get(w, None) else 1
# sort by number of occurrences
most_frequent = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])[-1][0]

print(most_frequent)
```

The output:

```
wolf
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler 2 liner:

```
word_count = {word: words.count(word) for word in set(words)}
print(max(word_count, key=word_count.get))
```

result:
`wolf`